# Grocery CRUD default value on GET

Tags: codeigniter-2, grocery-crud

Link to my page where grocery CRUD instance is, for example `index.php/users`.

When I add a new user, URL of the form is `index.php/users/index/add`, and I use link from external page, that points directly to `http://domain.com/index.php/users/index/add` to add new user without displaying the CRUD table first.

Now, I would like to set some default value via GET, for example `index.php/users/index/add?foo=bar`, and set some field's default value to `bar` if `$_GET['foo']` is set.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you'd like to combine get with this `$crud->field_type('office_id', 'hidden', $office_id);`

Which in this example:
office_id is the field,
hidden is the parameter so editor can't edit this field,
$office_id is the passed parameter(variable)

This way, office_id field will be always $office_id (which can you change)